# What is Minecraft Indev?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, terminology

Today I was watching a video of **iDeactiveMC** and found out that there is a old version of Minecraft called *Minecraft Indev*.

Please explain me exactly what Minecraft Indev is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indev, literally meaning "in development", was the [pre-beta version](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#Infdev) of Minecraft between December 2009 and February 2010. It was succeeded by Infdev, and then Alpha.

Basically, Minecraft development moved through a number of phases.

There was:

- The "pre-classic" era in mid 2009. The game was strictly single player creative.
- The multiplayer and survival tests a few months later.
- Indev, starting in early 2010 (version 0.31, though the version number wasn't being bumped to match releases for the later part of this)
- In*f*dev through mid 2010, which added infinite world generation (there used to be a hard limit on world sizes)
- Alpha, after June 2010, starting with 1.0.0. As I understand it, this was the point when people could actually buy the game.
- Beta 1.0 starting in December 2010, and going until November 2011
- And finally the release series, starting at 1.0.0 and stretching on to today.

There's not a whole lot to explain beyond this and the linked wiki article :)

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, edited. The link to the Minecraft wiki article there will give you the nitty gritty details, but here's a short timeline.